# How do I properly write scipy.stats.binom.cdf() details

Tags: python, statistics, probability, scipy

I need to calculate the probability of my random variable being $\le 0$. It's a binomial distribution, $10000$ trials, probability of success is $\frac{10}{19}$ (roughly $0.53$).

How do I properly use the `scipy.stats.binom.cdf()` to do that?

I've tried the following:

```
stats.binom(10000, a).cdf(0)
```

But it gives me an answer $0$.

I feel like I might be missing something about the formula itself.

Comment: Have a look at the [relevant SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html) and this [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678622/binomial-distribution-cdf-using-scipy-stats-binom-cdf).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from scipy.stats import binom
>>> binom.cdf(0, 10000,10/19)
0.0
```

Binomial random variable are nonnegative. Hence you want to compute the probability that it is equal to zero which is

$$\left(\frac{10}{19} \right)^{10000}\approx 10^{-2787.54}\approx 0$$

Comment: Siong, thank you!  I was trying to replicate the R function: `pbinom(1000/2-1, size = 1000, prob = 10/19)` from [link](https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/random-variables.html#the-probability-distribution-of-a-random-variable) , here is the working solution in Python `binom.cdf(1000/2 -1, 1000,10/19) ` with the result = $0.045$ .  What bothers me is that result changes so much when I change n from $1000$ to $10000$.  And deviates drastically from my similations that gives a similar to $0.045$ result.

Comment: i don't quite understand the description. Do you mean that as you change the $n$ from $1000$ to $10000$, there's some unexpected output?

Comment: @Polina, in the question you're asking for the cdf at zero, but in the code in your comment here you're asking for the cdf at 499 (or 4999)!  
From your link:
"Specifically, in our example above, we can show that (S+n)/2 follows a binomial distribution...to compute Pr(S<0) we note that
Pr(S<0)=Pr( (S+n)/2 < (0+n)/2 )."
Now that's given by the cdf of the binomial (S+n)/2 at n/2-1.

Answer (score 1):

Code would be:

```
n=10000
p=10/19
k=0
scipy.stats.binom.cdf(k,n,p)
```

However, before using any tool [R/Python/ or anything else for that matter], You should try to understand the concept.

**Concept of Binomial Distribution:**

Let’s assume that a trail is **repeated n times**. The happening of an event is called a **success** and the non-happening of the event is called **failure**.

Let ‘p’ be the probability of success and ‘q’ be the probability of failure in a single trial so that
**p + q = 1**

We assume that all trials are **independent** and ‘p’ and ‘q’ are **the same** in each trial.

Now, by **compound probability theorem for independent events**, the probability that first ‘r’ trials are the success and remaining ‘n – r’ trials are failure is

p^r*q^(n-r)

This expression shows the probability of ‘r’ continuous success and ‘n – r’ continuous failures. However, **‘r’ successes in n trials can occur in nCr ways** [Combinations of n things, taken r at a time: nCr = n! / r!(n - r)! = nPr / r! ]

Hence by multiplication theorem or probability/compound probability theorem/counting principle for independent events [insert hyperlink], the probability of getting ‘r’ success in ‘n’ trials is given by
P (r) = nCr p^r q^(n-r), **where ‘r’ can be considered as a discrete random variable** which takes values from **0, 1, 2, …, up to maximum ‘n’**

So theoretically too, x [binomial variate] taking value less than zero is not possible.  And

prob[x <= 0 ] = p[x = 0] = q^n

In your case this quantity is negligible.

I hope it helps!

Comment: what is the value k used for?

Comment: 'n' is the number of trials, 'p' is probability of success in a single trial, and 'k' is the number (of success you're looking for).
You asked for 'probability of random variable being ≤ 0' that's why k should be set to zero.
Hope it is clear.

Comment: scipy.stats.binom.cdf(k,n,p) = P[X <= k] for a binomial random variable X that comes up 1 with probability p, and has n trials. I'm just elaborating on your comment to make it more clear.